# GL_DEPTH_TEST fail in middle of program

Tags: opengl

was following some tutorial on learnopengl.com, moving camera around and suddenly the GL_DEPTH_TEST fails.

[GL_DEPTH_TEST WORKS AT FIRST, THEN FAILS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhIWa.jpg)

program looks like this

```
int main(){
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); //some draw function
    }
}
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{
    handler();
}
```

It actually fails in some other program as well (meaning other tutorials I am building). If I place the `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` in the loop, then it will not fail, so I suspects that GL_DEPTH_TEST has somehow been disabled / failed during runtime.

- Is there reason for this to happen?
- how to prevent it?
- is placing `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` in the loop the correct solution?
- is it hardware related? I am using Phenom X6 AMD CPU with some Radeon 6850 card on
  my Windows PC.

EDIT:

I think my window was actually quite standard stuff

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
int main(){
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewInit();
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){}
}
```

EDIT:

I used the function glIsEnabled() to check, indeed GL_DEPTH_TEST was disabled after sometime. This happens in 2 of the built program, one just panning around by key_press(change camera position), the other one rotates by glfwGetTime(). The line `if(!glIsEnabled(GL_DEPTH_TEST)) std::cout << "time: " << glfwGetTime() << "   no depth!!" << std::endl;` gave output.

Does google map WebGL in the background has anything to do with that?

I guess I shall have to resort to putting GL_DEPTH_TEST in loop.

Comment: There's probably more to it than you're showing here. For example, it's possible that your initial `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` call is made before the context is fully set up.

Comment: well, I still see the DEPTH TEST going on correctly in the first few hundred draws, but I am unsure what do you mean by context being fully setup. All the indicies, vertices, attribute pointers, shaders, textures are created before entering the loop.

Answer (score 1):

> - Is there reason for this to happen?

Normally not. OpenGL state is not supposed to suddenly change. However you have additional software installed, that injects DLLs and does "things to your OpenGL context. Programs like FRAPS (screen capture software), Stereoscopic/Virtual-Reality wrappers, Debugging-Overlays, etc.

> - how to prevent it?

Writing correct code ;) – and by that I mean the full stack: your program, the OS written by someone, the GPU drivers written by someone else. Bugs happen.

> - is placing glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) in the loop the correct solution?

Yes. In fact you should always set all drawing related state anew with each drawing iteration. Not only for correctness reasons, but because with more advanced rendering techniques eventually you'll have to do this anyway. For example if you're going to render shadow maps you'll have to use FBOs, which require to set glViewport several times during rendering a frame. Or say you want to draw a minimap and/or HUD, then you'll have to disable depth testing in between.

If your program is structured like this from the very beginning things are getting much easier.

> - is it hardware related?

No. OpenGL is a software level specification and a conforming implementation must do whatever the specification says, regardless of the underlying hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It may be your window declaration. Can you put your initialization for windows and opengl ?

**EDIT**

I can see you are declaring OpenGL 3.3, you have to put

```
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
```

before glewInit to make it works correctly.
Try to put it and control the eventual errors returned by glewInit :

```
GLuint err = glewInit();
```

> Does google map WebGL in the background has anything to do with that?

no it shouldn't because OpenGL doesn't share data between process.

Comment: Thanks, I will try again later tonight

Comment: bad luck, glewExperimental was already declared GL_TRUE, before glewInit(); glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT); glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);